# How to call the password from CreateAsync

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Lets say I have this.....

```
public async Task<IActionResult> CompleteRegistration(CompleteRegistrationViewModel model)
{             
var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);

return view(model)

}

public async Task<IActionResult> CreateRegistration(CreateRegistrationViewModel model)
{
.....
}
```

How can I call the Password in "var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);" inside the CreateRegistration ?

Comment: What do you mean by "call the Password"?

Comment: As in the information that has been placed as the password..... I want to call that in the action CreateRegistration @GabrielLuci